# How to auto close a matching quotes while using autoclose plugin on Vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, quotes

I use this [autoclose.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) plugin, since I want the auto close functionality.

When using Omnicompletion while editing HTML, this what I get.

```
<p id="
```

**Note the initial quotes...**

After entering some data, I proceeded to close the quotes, this being the output (notice the 3rd incorrect double quote):

```
<p id="sometext""
```

I'm aware that I can toggle the plugin with the ToggleAutoCloseMappings.
I thought also on deleting the existing quotes and opening some with the autoclose plugin then maybe it would help.

A more elegant solution would be to just close the existing quotes without toggling the plugin (it doesn't have to be autoclosed).

How can you tell it to autoclose the matching quote?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of two solutions:

1. The simplest one: just use `<C-v>"` when inserting quote after completion.
2. Use `<expr>` mapping where you try to check for the situation and run that plugin only when needed.

   ```
   " Put to ~/.vim/after/plugin/autoclose.vim
   let g:old_quote_rhs=substitute(maparg('"', 'i'), '<[^>]*>', '\=eval(''"\''.submatch(0).''"'')', 'g')
   inoremap <expr> " (HasUnclosedQuote() ? '"' : g:old_quote_rhs)
   ```

   The trickiest part is to write function `HasUnclosedQuote` right. Here is a simple implementation working only for unclosed quotes on the same line:

   ```
   function HasUnclosedQuote()
       return getline('.')[:(col('.')-1)]!~#'\v^%([^"]+|\"%(\\.|[^"\\]+)*\")*$'
   endfunction
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin only recognizes quotes that have been explicitly entered. When you introduce quotes from auto-completion (or register pastes), this isn't recognized and therefore results in the duplicate quote.

I guess there's little you can do except avoid inserting such incomplete quote fragments when the plugin is active.